# Redis vector similarity search syntax error

Tags: node.js, redis, embedding, cosine-similarity, similarity-search

Curently Im working on caching for out chatbot I resided to use native redis similarity search.
Their [node-redis](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) librarie provide interface to do it.
Ando also [LangchainJS](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/vectorstores/integrations/redis/) has options for caching, but it wont work as I need it, because I already have embeddings to save and search with, and Embedding class wont work (maybe it can, but this will be crutches), so I desided to write custom solution with node-redis. And here the problem...

Here in their [documentation](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/search/vectors/) they have examples how to work with KNN queries
`FT.SEARCH idx "*=>[KNN 10 @vec $BLOB]" PARAMS 2 BLOB "\x12\xa9\xf5\x6c" DIALECT 2` and it work (at least there is no errors) if I use it in termila or RedisInsight, but when I'm trying to run this query with nodejs it throws error `[ErrorReply: Syntax error at offset 2 near > ]`

```
async function searchSimilar(vector: number[]) {
  const query = `* => [KNN 10 @embedding $BLOB]`;

  const options = {
    PARAMS: {
      BLOB: Buffer.from(new Float32Array(vector).buffer),
      DIALECT: 2,
    },
  };

  const result = await client.ft.search("idx:answers", query, options);

  return result;
}
```

Maybe I didn't understand how it works...
Here the example how it work in Langchain

```
    async similaritySearchVectorWithScore(query, k, filter) {
        if (filter && this.filter) {
            throw new Error("cannot provide both `filter` and `this.filter`");
        }
        const _filter = filter ?? this.filter;
        const results = await this.redisClient.ft.search(this.indexName, ...this.buildQuery(query, k, _filter));
        const result = [];
        if (results.total) {
            for (const res of results.documents) {
                if (res.value) {
                    const document = res.value;
                    if (document.vector_score) {
                        result.push([
                            new Document({
                                pageContent: document[this.contentKey],
                                metadata: JSON.parse(this.unEscapeSpecialChars(document.metadata)),
                            }),
                            Number(document.vector_score),
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    buildQuery(query, k, filter) {
        const vectorScoreField = "vector_score";
        let hybridFields = "*";
        // if a filter is set, modify the hybrid query
        if (filter && filter.length) {
            // `filter` is a list of strings, then it's applied using the OR operator in the metadata key
            // for example: filter = ['foo', 'bar'] => this will filter all metadata containing either 'foo' OR 'bar'
            hybridFields = `@${this.metadataKey}:(${this.prepareFilter(filter)})`;
        }
        const baseQuery = `${hybridFields} => [KNN ${k} @${this.vectorKey} $vector AS ${vectorScoreField}]`;
        const returnFields = [this.metadataKey, this.contentKey, vectorScoreField];
        const options = {
            PARAMS: {
                vector: this.getFloat32Buffer(query),
            },
            RETURN: returnFields,
            SORTBY: vectorScoreField,
            DIALECT: 2,
            LIMIT: {
                from: 0,
                size: k,
            },
        };
        return [baseQuery, options];
    }
    getFloat32Buffer(vector) {
        return Buffer.from(new Float32Array(vector).buffer);
    }
```

Here I found one more example in Python, and I can't understand why my query doesn't work

```py
def create_query(
   return_fields: list,
   search_type: str="KNN",
   number_of_results: int=20,
   vector_field_name: str="img_vector",
   gender: t.Optional[str] = None,
   category: t.Optional[str] = None
):
   tag = "("
   if gender:
       tag += f"@gender:{{{gender}}}"
   if category:
       tag += f"@category:{{{category}}}"
   tag += ")"
   # if no tags are selected
   if len(tag) < 3:
       tag = "*"

   base_query = f'{tag}=>[{search_type} {number_of_results} @{vector_field_name} $vec_param AS vector_score]'
   return Query(base_query)\
       .sort_by("vector_score")\
       .paging(0, number_of_results)\
       .return_fields(*return_fields)\
       .dialect(2)
```

I've read documentations, searched internet, opened issues and discussions on GitHub and researched build of node js libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/a7d5bc7ca4da6cde66140ae4fea96a8ea6e7ce64/examples/search-knn.js#L57). The `DIALECT` attribute should appear on its own, and not as part of the `PARAMS`, which should include only parameters for the query itself (like the `BLOB` in your example).

Basically you passed the `DIALECT` as a parameter for the query (even though it is not used there), while the parsing itself was done using the default dialect, which is currently 1 (can be changed with `FT.CONFIG SET DEFAULT_DIALECT <n>`). KNN search is not available in dialect 1 so you get a syntax error.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. I just got tired and put `DIALECT` into the wrong section.
It's important to take a step back and rest sometime and not push it